# Accessing DDR memory address between (2GB-4Gb) through DSP DMA 64bit addressing

Tags: 64-bit, signal-processing, memory-address, dma

We are trying to access the DDR addresses of more than 2Gb to 4Gb through ShimDMA where it is more than 32 bits. Is DMA supports more than 32 bit addressing of physical memory ? We are using below api's for it OctSysDmaMemWrite, OctSysDmaMemRead.

Answer (score 1):

The hardware supports more than 32-bit. However, the DSP kernel APIs don't. We will try to add this to the next release (3.20).